# Break statement is not in loop or switch statement?

Tags: c++, break

I am having trouble with my code, I have read other forums this site about this problem but they don't really relate to my situation. I am new to C++, I barely have about 3 weeks into the course. I do not know why my break statement isn't working, to me it is in the loop. What am I missing?

```
float a[60][7];
int row;
cout << "How many students would you like to grade?" << endl;

cin >> studentNum;

cout << "Enter grades for the first student" << endl;

row = 0;
n = studentNum - 2;

while (row < studentNum)
{
    a[row][0]=k;
    a[row][0] = row;
    cout << "Enter grade for test 1: ";
    cin >> a[row][1];
    cout << "Enter grade for test 2: ";
    cin >> a[row][2];
    cout << "Enter grade for test 3: ";
    cin >> a[row][3];
    cout << "Enter grade for test 4: ";
    cin >> a[row][4];



    a[row][5] = (a[row][1] + a[row][2] + a[row][3] + a[row][4]) / 4;
    a[row][6] = a[row][1] * 0.2 + a[row][2] * 0.3 + a[row][3] * 0.3 + a[row][4] * 0.2;

    row++;
}
if (row == n)
{
    cout << "Enter Grades for the last Student" << endl;
    cout << "Enter grade for test 1: ";
    cin >> a[row][1];
    cout << "Enter grade for test 2: ";
    cin >> a[row][2];
    cout << "Enter grade for test 3: ";
    cin >> a[row][3];
    cout << "Enter grade for test 4: ";
    cin >> a[row][4];
    break;
}
else
{ 
   cout << "Enter grades for the next student" << endl;
   row = row + 1;
}



cout << "Stdnt" << "\t" << "Grade1" << "\t" << "Grade2" << "\t" << "Grade3" << "\t" << "Grade4" << "\t" << "Avg1" << "\t" << "Avg2" << endl;
printarray(a, studentNum);

cin.get();
return 0;
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that `break` at the end of the `if`?

Comment: Would really appreciate the help, I'm taking the course online to get ahead but I know see that it was a mistake, and my prof. won't respond to my emails :(

Comment: @Michael I want the statement "Enter grades for the last student " to end the grading with the last student. but as for right now, when i run the program, "enter grades for the last student " doesn't even pop up and "Enter grades for the last student" comes up at the very bottom of the program

Comment: You'll probably have to move the `if` and the `else` inside the `while` loop, setting `while (row <= n)` if I understood you correctly. Remove the break.
Check my answer for details.

Comment: Yes! thanks a lot :) @Michael

Comment: You are welcome. If you think my answer solved your problem, please accept it as answer.

Comment: okay, now I am encountering another problem. You fixed the break and the statements. but now my array isn't printing out the last row of grades. for example, I input 3 students to grade, my array should print out 3 rows and 7 columns. but the last row just shows 0 0 0 0 0 0 0, the 1st col, should be the number of the student, next four should be the 4 grades and last two should be 2 avge grades. i have my calculations there, not sure why the last row isn't printing.

Comment: That's probably because `studentNum` is equal to `n-2`, while `a` has a size of `n`. Instead of passing `studentNum`, pass `n` to the `printArray()` function. Anyway, without seeing the implementation of `printArray()`, I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
float a[60][7];
int row = 0;

std::cout << "How many students would you like to grade?" << std::endl;
std::cin >> studentNum;

n = studentNum - 2;

std::cout << "Enter grades for the first student" << std::endl;
while (row <= n)
{
  a[row][0] = k;
  a[row][0] = row;
  std::cout << "Enter grade for test 1: ";
  std::cin >> a[row][1];
  std::cout << "Enter grade for test 2: ";
  std::cin >> a[row][2];
  std::cout << "Enter grade for test 3: ";
  std::cin >> a[row][3];
  std::cout << "Enter grade for test 4: ";
  std::cin >> a[row][4];


  a[row][5] = (a[row][1] + a[row][2] + a[row][3] + a[row][4]) / 4;
  a[row][6] = a[row][1] * 0.2 + a[row][2] * 0.3 + a[row][3] * 0.3 + a[row][4] * 0.2;

  if (row==n)
  {
    std::cout << "Enter Grades for the last Student" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter grade for test 1: ";
    std::cin >> a[row][1];
    std::cout << "Enter grade for test 2: ";
    std::cin >> a[row][2];
    std::cout << "Enter grade for test 3: ";
    std::cin >> a[row][3];
    std::cout << "Enter grade for test 4: ";
    std::cin >> a[row][4];
  }
  else
  { 
    std::cout << "Enter grades for the next student" << std::endl;
  }

  row++;
}

std::cout << "Student" << "\t" << "Grade1" << "\t" << "Grade2" << "\t" << "Grade3" << "\t" << "Grade4" << "\t" << "Avg1" << "\t" << "Avg2" << std::endl;
printarray(a, studentNum);

std::cin.get();
return 0;
```

P.S. edit with fixed while

Comment: Remove the extra row++ in the else clause.